# 8051 serial debug monitors

Tags: debugging, 8051, iar, keil

I'm working with an 8051 (Cypress FX2LP) that doesn't have jtag/bdm capability. Typically, developers on this project have been using ad-hoc serial printfs for debugging. I'm looking into options for serial debug monitors such as Keil's Mon51, Isd51 or IAR's generic ROM-monitor.

I'll need to modify/configure this debug monitor to write to code RAM (to set software breakpoints). I'd guess that most 8051 debug monitors offer the ability for such modifications in order to support Harvard architecture or bank switching.

Does anybody have recommendations for serial debuggers for 8051 or similar processors?

Have you had to modify it to write to Harvard code RAM or flash etc?

Comment: You will get better responses on chiphacker.com.

Answer (score 1):

I used for years Keil uVision PK51 and the [Cypress FX2 EZ-USB Development kit](http://www.cypress.com/?rID=14319). This kit (EZ-USB_devtools_version_261700.zip) worked correctly with FX2 and FX2LP.
It includes a Windows driver that automatically downloads the monitor firmware on board and stay resident in 8051 memory. This monitor takes control of one of the 2 serial board and manage the communication with the debugging tool. You have to set the Keil environment debugger to use the "Keil Monitor-51 driver".

Once your fw is downloaded and running you can set breakpoints, display watch, etc...

The Cypress driver works correctly with Windows 2K/XP. I never tried it with Vista or later. Probably there is a newer version of the Cypress that is able to run on the latest Windows.

Good luck

Comment: Any suggestions to modify the Monitor-51 code to access code-space? For 8051's with loadable code in external memory, it seems to be typical that a port pin is used to allow the loader to write to code space. I've had troubles getting source for the Monitor-51 code that comes with the dev kit. Keil suggests asking Cypress and Cypress suggests asking Keil.

Comment: Unofrtunately I haven't. I tried in the past without any luck. I know that there is a folder in the Cyspress dev kit (\Cypress\USB\Target\Monitor) with various version of the monitor and README that explains how they work.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Mon51 with the Cypress FX2 for going on 10 years with very good success.  In addition we use the RTXtiny task switcher and code banking.  I have found the monitor to be generally solid and with enough functionality for our needs.

The Mon-51 code comes as a library from Keil, so it is not available.  A couple of years ago I was having trouble getting code banking to work with the monitor, and since I wasn't getting very good support from Keil, I started to disassemble the monitor to figure out what was going wrong.  Before I got very far I solved my problem and I never finished the reverse engineering project.

Our hardware platform is "von-neumanized" so that code and xdata space overlap.  This is necessary for the monitor to work correctly.  We have modified the monitor initialization code so that it runs at 115200 baud from an external uart and that works well.  In addition we had to build our own version of the monitor so that it was located at a different location in memory.  Keil has actually made it pretty easy to configure things without having to dive into the actual monitor code.